# Installing apps --- Unknown Sources

Tags: unknown-sources

Where do you find the Unknown Sources option on Android 5.0 and/or Edge 6+?  I don't find the option under Applications or Application Manager.

Comment: It is under _System_ Tab --> _Security_ --> Unkown Sources

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings` and locate `Lock screen and security`.
Scroll down and enable `Unknown Sources`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under **Security** in Settings as seen in photo. In Android 5.0, *Security* is under **General** tab.

[image]